# http-server: How to disable charset for .wasm files?

Tags: macos, server, mime, webassembly, charset

I am running a https server (Apache?) on my Mac. Done by this hints:

https://medium.com/@jonsamp/how-to-set-up-https-on-localhost-for-macos-b597bcf935ee

It serves my wasm-files with charset and I get: TypeError: WebAssembly: Response has unsupported MIME type 'application/wasm; charset=utf-8' expected 'application/wasm'

Changing  .htaccess  by adding
*AddType 'application/wasm' .wasm*
does not help. It feels like the server ignores  .htaccess